# How to attach pop-up window to the page

Tags: javascript, html, css

SCRIPT

```
<SCRIPT TYPE="text/javascript">
  <!--
    function popup(mylink, windowname)
    {
      if (! window.focus)return true;
        var href;
        if (typeof(mylink) == 'string')
          href=mylink;
        else
         href=acc_like;
      window.open(href, windowname, 'width=400,height=200,scrollbars=yes');
      return false;
    }
  //-->
</SCRIPT>
```

HTML

```
<BODY onLoad="popup('autopopup.html', 'ad')">
```

I am getting popup window, but I don't want it to minimize when user clicks away outside of it.

Comment: If you want to have it static on your site, than you should not create a new windows. You could embed it in your existing window

Comment: It's note possibile without any code or knowing of your site. Maybe you want to open the new html-file in an iframe.

Comment: What do you mean by attach? Just put the content of the pop-up in your page. Looking at your code above though I'm guessing this about advertisements.

Comment: “I Need To Attach This Popup Window To Html page So that user will Always see it” — I don’t understand what you mean by that.

Comment: I want it not to minimize when User Click Away From It.

Comment: You mean you want it inside your HTML page? There's stuff like [jQuery dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/) for that

Comment: @Johan: you can’t stop a user from minimising or closing a browser window that you open via JavaScript. Their browser windows are their business, whether you opened them or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion you should use [jquery dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/) to get what you want, the sample below (try it on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/P79nL/)):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>  
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
                modal: true <!-- is background page responsive or not --> 
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>      
    Background information
    <div id="dialog-form" title="Hello">Basic information</div> 
</body>
</html>
```